# How to sum the values of two rows in sql server

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT (
    (SUM(t_price) - SUM(a_dvpay)) - (
        SELECT SUM(inst_amount)
        FROM installment
        WHERE uid = user_info.uid
    )        
) AS remaining
FROM user_info
WHERE faculty_id = @faculty_id
GROUP BY uid;
```

This SQL query return the **remaining result** in multiple rows. I want to sum the values of remaining as **Total remaining**.
[SQL Query Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLIoV.png)

Comment: Alias the result and sum that column

Comment: mysql and sql-server refers different, pls. choose any one of them.

Comment: what is the expected result ?

Comment: Check the screen shot you will clear what i want...my expected result is 165450 + 22000 = 187450

Answer (score 1):

Remove the Group By clause.

```
SELECT ((sum(t_price) - sum(a_dvpay))-(select sum(inst_amount) from installment where uid=user_info.uid)) as remaining  FROM user_info WHERE (faculty_id = @faculty_id)**strong text**
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that return what you needed:

```
SELECT SUM(remaining) FROM (
    SELECT sum(t_price - a_dvpay) as remaining  
    FROM user_info
    WHERE faculty_id = 1
    UNION
    SELECT -SUM(COALESCE(inst_amount,0))
    FROM installment inst
    WHERE uid IN (SELECT DISTINCT user_info.uid FROM user_info WHERE faculty_id = 1)
) x
```

Test it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e6d341/11

Answer (score 0):

So it will be the sum of the amount(s) inside `installment` table, and I assume that not all members under a given `faculty_id` has a record there. In order to cater that, I used `COALESCE` to handle `NULLS` in the `installment` table:

```
SELECT ui.uid, 
    (SUM(ui.t_price) - SUM(ui.a_dvpay)) - SUM(COALESCE(i.inst_amount, 0)) `remaining`
FROM user_info ui
    LEFT JOIN installment i ON i.uid = ui.uid
WHERE faculty_id = @faculty_id
GROUP BY ui.uid;
```

Comment: faculty id is same in all cases '1'..but your query give different result on my expectation.

Comment: You can check using the formula you have given, I just replicate the formula that you have used in the question